# why doesn't this "boost::bind" compile?

Tags: c++, function, boost, bind

I'm trying to use boost::bind with boost::function,but a compile error appeared.
why can't bind a placeholder to the function object?

```
void fun_1(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    std::cout<<"test_1------------"<<std::endl;
}
void fun_2(int i)
{
    std::cout<<"tset_2------------"<<std::endl;
}
int main(void)
{
    boost::function0<void> fobj;
    //fobj = boost::bind(&fun_1,boost::asio::placeholders::error);//compile failed
    fobj = boost::bind(&fun_2,5);//syntax is ok
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's is the error? Do you include the relevant asio header? Does it compile if you use _1 instead of the asio placeholder?

Comment: there is a long error message about template instantiation,I think i have included all necessary headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:**
by looking at http://my.oschina.net/yellia/blog/90678, the author explains the implementation of boost::bind clearly and simply. I hope it would help you.哈哈

Comment: The link is in Chinese. Can you please edit your answer and post the translated version?

Answer (score 2):

Your signatures don't match. Try this:

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

void fun_1(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    std::cout<<"test_1------------"<<std::endl;
}
void fun_2(int i)
{
    std::cout<<"tset_2------------"<<std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    boost::function<void (const boost::system::error_code&)> fobj;
    fobj = boost::bind(&fun_1,boost::asio::placeholders::error);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation tested under gcc with `g++ main.cpp -lboost_system -lpthread`

For future reference, it helps to add

- fully compilable examples
- the complete compilation/linker error message

when posting snippets like the above to save people that want to help you time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer，I've tried this way before I ask this question，but I don't want to change the declaration of “fobj”，This is exactly what I want to verify."boost::bind(&fun_2,5)"can compile,"boost::bind(&fun_1,boost::asio::placeholders::error)" can not.what's the difference between these two functions,they have  same number of parameters，just different type,were placeholders  specially treated?

Comment: @user1834749 The difference is that `bind(&fun_2,5)` creates a "nullar" function object that doesn't accept additional arguments, while `bind(&fun_1, praceholders::error)` or `bind(&fun_1, _1)` create a function object with arity 1, i.e. with 1 argument -- which should be supplied by the caller: `fobj(someError)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you cant change the signature you need to pass the value for the `error_code` to bind instead of a placeholder, so that it can supplied when the function is called

i.e.:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>

void fun_1(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    std::cout<<"test_1------------"<<std::endl;
}
void fun_2(int i)
{
    std::cout<<"tset_2------------"<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    boost::function0<void> fobj;
    //fobj = boost::bind(&fun_1,boost::asio::placeholders::error);//compile failed

    fobj = boost::bind( &fun_1,
            boost::system::errc::make_error_code( boost::system::errc::success ) );//compiles ok

    // fobj = boost::bind(&fun_2,5);//syntax is ok
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: aha,it works,thanks.I think I need to access more infomation about that how `placeholders::error` converts to `system::error_code&` when we use `async_read` or `async_write` with `bind `.

Comment: @user1834749 if you are happy with the answer could you click the tick to accept it.